# Hive conditional count by resetting counter?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have two hive tables, customers and transaction.

```
customer table
---------------------------------
customer_id | account_threshold 
---------------------------------
101          |   200            
102          |   500            

transaction table
-------------------------------------------
 transaction_date  | customer_id | amount  
-------------------------------------------
  07/01/2018            101         250 
  07/01/2018            102         450   
  07/02/2018            101         500 
  07/03/2018            102         100 
  07/04/2018            102         50  

Result:
------------------------------
  customer_id  | breach_count
------------------------------
    101             2
    102             1
```

I have to count the number of instances the sum of amount in transaction table exceeds the account_threshold in customer table.
When a breach is detected I reset the counter to 0.

For customer 101, the first transaction is above threshold so, the breach count is 1. Then again there is a breach for 101 in 3rd transaction. Hence, the total breach count for 101 is 2.
for customer 102, the first transaction(450) is below the threshold. Next transaction for 102 is $100 which breaches the threshold of 500, so breach_count will be 1.

I have tried windowing but I am not able to get any clue how to proceed by joining two tables.

Comment: Why `customer_id   = 102` `breach_count` is 1 instead of 2?

Comment: Customer 102 has three transaction of 450, 100 and 50. Their threshold value is 500. So, after second transaction the threshold is breached so, count is 1. The third transaction of 50 doesn't breach the limit so, the final value is 1.

Comment: Ok I edit my answer you need to order by amount in Windows function @Partha Deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write a subquery to get accumulate `amount` order by `amount` by `customer_id`, then `Outer JOIN` base on `customer` then `Count`

```
SELECT t.customer_id, COUNT(t.totle) breach_count
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN
(
  select t1.*,SUM(t1.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.customer_id order by t1.amount) as totle
  from transaction1 t1
) t on c.customer_id = t.customer_id 
WHERE c.account_threshold < t.totle
GROUP BY t.customer_id
```

Here is a [sqlfildde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0df17/2) from Sqlserver, although different DBMS, but the windows function syntax is the same

**[Results]**:

```
| customer_id | breach_count |
|-------------|--------------|
|         101 |            2 |
|         102 |            1 |
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 7:37 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'totle'`

Comment: Ok I guess I miss the `AS` for Alisa name, edit my answer you can try it, and move the condition to `WHERE`

Comment: @Partha Deb I saw I write the wrong column in the subquery you can try it now:)

Answer (score 0):

To reset count/rank/sum whenever value changes

Input table :- 
Time  | value 
12       |A
13       |A
14       |C
15       |C
16       |B
17       |B
18       |A

You just need to take lag to know about previous value 
Step 1.Select *, lag(status)  as lagval

Now compare lag value to actual value and if it differs take it 1 else 0 ( take this column as flag) 
Step 2. Select * , case when lagval! = status then 1 else 0

Now do sum over flag take it as running sum - you will get sum values different for each group, group means whenver value changed its a new group
 Step 3. Select *, sum(flag)  over (order by time) flag_sum

Now just row number on each group

Step 4.Select Rownumber() over (partition by flag_sum order by time)

Final result

Time  | value | lagval | flag | flag_sum  | rownumber
12       |A     | null   | 1         | 1           | 1
13       |A     | A      |0           |1            |2
14       |C     |A       |1           |2            |1
15       |C     | C      |0           |2            |2
16       |B      |C      |1           | 3           |1
17       |B     |B       |0           |3            |2
18       |A     |B      |1            |4            |1

You can use sum / count in place of rownumber whatever you want to reset whenever value changes.

Comment: Add some code or link to examples without it it can be hard to understand for others.